# Swift: Override function during initialization (See what I mean in Java example)

Tags: java, swift, overriding, implementation

In Java, lets say we have a class named Card. This class has a method getAction() and returns an object of class Action.

I know it is possible to override this method during init. Like this:

```
Card card = new Card() { 
   @Override
   public Action getCard() {
      return Action...
   }
}
```

My Question is if you can do this in Swift language, or do you simply need to create a class for every different override of the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring in Java is called [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) - you are actually declaring a one-time derived class inline.

**Unfortunately** Swift doesn't have this feature.

**But** you can consider passing a closure to the instance.

Lets say that your Card class have a var `getCardFunction`:

```
Class Card {
  var getCardFunction : () -> Int
}
```

Now you can pass the function you desire after initialising:

```
var card = Card()
card.getCardFunction = {
  return 6
}
```

***Note***: you can even have a default value for the `getCardFunction` function:

```
Class Card {
  var getCardFunction : () -> Int = {
    return 3
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in Swift, you must have to create a class, then you have to inheritance from that class and override the methods.

You can do an alternative like this response: [Swift: Override object method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28679151/3701102)